# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.store' doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-validation, laravel-migrations, laravel-request

When I try to save data from laravel form to a database table I am getting the following exception:

**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.store' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `store` where `name` = samplename)**

the table store exists but still I am getting the error

this is my contoller that is processing the form:

```
 <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\storestore;
    use App\Http\Requests\storeFormRequest;



    class AddstoreController extends Controller
    {
        //

        public function create()
        {
            //

        }

        public function store( storeFormRequest $request)
        {

            $store = new Store;
            $store->name = Input::get('name');
            $store->description = Input::get('description');
            $store->store_vendor_id = Input::get('owner');
            $store->contact_email = Input::get('contact_email');
            $store->postal_address = Input::get('postal_address');
            $store->city = Input::get('city');
            $store->zip = Input::get('zip');
            $store->phone = Input::get('phone');
            $store->business_logo = Input::get('logo');
            $store->save();
            return \Redirect::route('add_store_success')
          ->with('message', 'Thanks for joining us!');
        }
    }
```

This is my **Store** model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Store extends Model
{
    //

    protected $table = 'stores';

     protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'vendor_id',
     'contact_email','postal_address','city','zip','phone',
     'meta_description','business_logo'];

 }
```

StoreRequest file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

use App\StoreController;


class StoreFormRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
    'name' => 'required|unique:dstore',
    'vendor_id' => 'required',
    'contact_email' => 'required|email|max:100|unique:dstore',

    'business_logo' => 'required',

        ];

         //validate
        if ($validation->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
        }

    }


}
```

These are the **get** and **post** routes:

```
Route::get('/store_form', ['as' => 'add_store_form', 'uses' => 'StoreController@create']);
Route::post('/store_form',['as' => 'dstore', 'uses' => 'StoreController@store']);
```

Both routes are listed when I run ***php artisan route:list*** command

I have tried to goggle for solution but the one I landed on pointed out to missing tables as a course, but in my case the store table is existing but still I am getting the error.

Any help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `Store` model class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Store extends Model
{
    //

    protected $table = 'stores';

     protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'vendor_id',
     'contact_email','postal_address','city','zip','phone',
     'meta_description','business_logo'];

}
```

As you see property `$table` is set to `stores` so I assume table name in your database is `stores` and not `store`.

You should probably change in your `StoreFormRequest` content or `rules` method to use in `unique` rule  valid table name, for example:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        //
'name' => 'required|unique:stores',
'vendor_id' => 'required',
'contact_email' => 'required|email|max:100|unique:stores',

'business_logo' => 'required',

    ];

     //validate
    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
    }

}
```